# Is there a command or api can turn on/off wifi function on windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, wifimanager

For the project requirement, I need to find a way to turn on/off wifi function on Windows8 without mouse click.
I search solution over Internet for a while, I only found the way to [access Radio state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.networkoperators.mobilebroadbandradiostate)
Does anyone who familiar with windows can give me direction? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is possible at all (to change wifi state). You could try to disable the wireless network adapter.

Comment: @Cthulhu Not only it's possible, it's an OS requirement for Wi-Fi drivers

Comment: @icepack I've not used software that turned on my wireless on its own, so I assumed it wasn't possible. My bad.

Comment: you don't need such software, it's doable even via windows mobility center

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SetRadioState method from IRadioInterface interface to toggle Wi-Fi radio state.

Answer (score 0):

How about cmd functions?

1) turn off wifi

netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=disabled

2) turn on wifi

netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=enabled

3) connect some AP (%1 is the name of the ssid)

netsh wlan connect name=%1 ssid=%1 interface="Wi-Fi"